# Ansible merge lists of many matched group_vars

Tags: linux, ansible

We have many servers groups, for example :

- MTL (servers located in Montreal)
- OTA (servers located in Ottawa)
- DMZ (reverse proxies exposed to internet)
- APP (applicative servers)
- CUSTOMER_X (server that contains customer X)
- CUSTOMER_Y (server that contains customer Y)

Each server group have their own cron jobs, and a server can belong to many matched and unmatched groups (a server can be in all groups MTL, DMZ, APP, CUSTOMER_Y and CUSTOMER_X).

What we want to do is to merge all "cron_jobs" list of matching group_vars of a given server.

Is that possible ? Else, is there a way to achieve equivalent ?

We could of course do :

```
crons: "{{ all_crons + dmz_crons + mtl_crons }}" # etc ..
```

But that would be redneck as hell considering we have hundreds of groups

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Actually specific crons are manually entered in servers, we want to all automate it. For example APP servers have their own crons, MTL servers have their own crons etc ..

with_flattened won't do the trick since the same reason as `crons: "{{ all_crons + dmz_crons + mtl_crons }}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a role for each function (OTA, MTL, DMZ, APP, CUSTOMER_X, CUSTOMER_Y)

```
- hosts: dmz
  roles:
    - { role: dmz}   
- hosts: ota
  become: yes
  roles:
    - { role: ota}       
- hosts: app
  become: yes
  roles:
    - { role: app}
```

Each role does specific configuration for the function (i.e. dmz configures a dmz) and it also adds the needed cron jobs.

You can optimize the roles, avoiding repeating code, by using a common role that is added as a dependency on the meta folder.

Example, in role `app` folder `meta`, create a file main.yml with the following content:

```
dependencies:
  - { role: common,
      common_cron_job: "{{app_common_cron_job}}"
    }
```

The value of `app_common_cron_job` can be set in each ansible group, for example
 group_vars\app

The common role will have the needed task to create the cron job using the provided value in `common_cron_job`.  If you need more than a single job for each group, modify the code to pass a struct of jobs.

See my tutorial [Creating a Kubernetes Cluster with Vagrant and Ansible](https://www.itwonderlab.com/ansible-kubernetes-vagrant-tutorial/) for a full example of how to use meta folders and dependencies. See my tutorial [Using Ansible for Terraform Managed AWS Infrastructure](https://www.itwonderlab.com/using-ansible-for-terraform-managed-aws-infrastructure/) for an example on how to use group vars.

A host that is present in many groups will end up executing a role for each of its groups and the value of common_cron_job will change to be whatever the groupvars define for that group. At the end all the needed cron jobs will be created.

Be aware that you will also need a way to clear created cron jobs that are not needed anymore (tip: use a common_cron_job_delete var and its corresponding task).